# Android how to design tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like the screen to look like the image displayed below. I have tried to implement this design using a table layout, but this does not look correct. Please suggest any other techniques.[image]

Comment: Use a `GridLayout`, or a `ConstraintLayout`, or a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: can you plz post some code related to GridLayoutManager because I dont have any idea about it

Comment: RelativeLayout as main layout (parent) then add other RelativeLayout as children, in which add imageView and textView

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/Grid

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare it works for me.you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below. Just adjust the margin. Should look like what you need. You can also wrap all inside a ScrollView.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/lt1"
            android:layout_width="163.0dip"
            android:layout_height="230.0dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="6dp">


          <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im1"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="@color/your_bg"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/your_string"
                android:cropToPadding="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/account"
                android:textColor="@color/your_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lt1"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/lt2"
            android:layout_width="163.0dip"
            android:layout_height="235.0dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lt1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lt1"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im2"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lt2"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/lt3"
            android:layout_width="163.0dip"
            android:layout_height="235.0dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/lt1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="5dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="your_bg"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im3"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/services"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/services" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/im3"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/lt4"
            android:layout_width="163.0dip"
            android:layout_height="235.0dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/lt2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="12.0dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lt3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lt3"
            android:background="@drawable/your_bg">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
                android:text="@string/other_detail"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im4"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/your_string"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/your_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```